# Microsoft Edge doesn'l load webpages in Ubuntu 22.04 for one particular user account

Tags: 22.04

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

There are no issues with internet connectivity or the websites which I tried to access.
Other browsers (chrome, opera, firefox) works fine and load webpages.

But msedge is unable to load webpages. [error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3CoM.png)

Fixes that I have tried:

1. After updating browser, restarting it from the "About" page of edge resolved this issue once.
2. Reset browser settings, cleared all cached data and cookies.
3. Uninstalled and reinstalled the browser. (was of no help)
4. Restarted the system (was of no help)

The issue seems to be random and I couldnt reproduce it. I have two users in my system and the issue exists only on this user. Installed edge as root user. Edge can load webpages from the other user. First two of the above fixes resolved the issue temporarily but now they are of no help.

--edit--
By user I mean the user accounts in the machine not the msedge user accounts.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you had a look around the user's directory (including hidden files)? `cd ~username` to get into the user's directory. Then something like: `find . -iname '*edge*'` to see where the profile is stored. Then rename it: `mv dirname dirname.bak`

Comment: Wouldn't I lose my profile details then?

Comment: @zaindeen That shouldn't matter because you already "Reset browser settings, cleared all cached data and cookies." And if you wanted to keep something, you could always move the folder back after testing this

Comment: I copied the entire config files from `/home/user1/.config/microsoft-edge`(working one) to `/home/user2/.config/microsoft-edge` but this time the browser didn't even start up. Upon trying to run from terminal I encountered these errors: **msedge_crashpad_handler database is required** and **ERROR:socket.cc(120)] recvmsg: Connection reset ... **

Comment: That "database is required" error is caused by that folder being owned by the wrong user after copying: https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftEdge/comments/11a7zfi/microsoft_edge_will_not_open_on_macbook_air_with/ Try a `chown -R username:username folder`